# Concatenating strings with ints in Python: Jack and the Beanstalk

Tags: python

I am new to python and am having trouble concatenating my print string to display the data the way I want it displayed. I  know very little of python, and have been trying to do this using mostly what I know from java. An explanation of a proper format would be helpful, Thanks in advance.

Code:

```
print("The Magic Beanstalk\n")

height = 100
hours = input("Enter a number of hours: ")

string1 = "After 1 hour, the beanstalk was %d cm tall.", height

print(string1)

for i in hours:

    height = height*1.5 + 30
    print("After %d hours, the beanstalk was %d cm tall. ", hours, height)

print("And it's still growing!!!")
```

Output:

```
The Magic Beanstalk


Enter a number of hours: 3

('After 1 hour, the beanstalk was %d cm tall.', 100)

After %d hours, the beanstalk was %d cm tall.  3 180.0

And it's still growing!!!
```

As you can see I tried printing it out from a call to an object and a print statement directly, neither of which are giving me the result I am looking for.

Comment: `string1` is a tuple; if you want a string with `%d` replaced by `height`, you need to use a `%`, not a `,`.

Answer (score 1):

You can do either

```
string1 = "After 1 hour, the beanstalk was {} cm tall.".format(height)
print("After {} hours, the beanstalk was {} cm tall. ".format(hours, height))
```

or 
    string1 = f"After 1 hour, the beanstalk was {height} cm tall."
    print(f"After {hours} hours, the beanstalk was {height} cm tall. ")
The second option of f string is from python 3.6 or higher.

Comment: Thank you! can I ask why the f is required and what the second method is called?

Comment: You welcome, f string it's new in python as explained since 3.6 before that the format method was mostly used to adding params to a string,

Answer (score 0):

Try this way with format specifiers:

```
string1 = "After 1 hour, the beanstalk was %d cm tall." % height
```

or with format method:

```
string1 = "After 1 hour, the beanstalk was {0} cm tall.".format(height)
```